# Unweighted graphs using Adjacency lists

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm new to programming and trying to learn data structures on my own. I am trying to implement an unweighted graph class using adjacency lists, but I am having trouble implementing the getAdjacentVertices method and I don't exactly know how the addEdge method is really working specially how to implement the insertAtTheBeginning method.Please help me, the book I am using doesn't really explains this topics.*

```
enter code here
public class Graph {
    private ArrayList<Integer> vertices;
    private ListNode[] edges;
    private int vertexCount = 0;
    public Graph(int vertexCount){
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount;
        vertices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        edges = new ListNode[vertexCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++){
            vertices.add(i);
            edges[i] = new ListNode ();
         }
    }
    public void addEdge(int source, int destination){
       int i = vertices.indexOf(source);
       int j = vertices.indexOf(destination);
       if(i != -1 || j != -1){
          edges[i].insertAtBeginning(destination);
          edges[j].insertAtBeginning(source);
       }
    }
    public int getNumberVertices() {
       return vertexCount;
    }
    public Object getAdjacentVertices(int currentVertex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions,

- `getAdjacentVertices(i)` can simply return the `i`-th element of `edges`.
- `addEdge()` doesn't have to add to the beginning. Unless you have a specific reason for imposing an order on the neighbor list, most graph algorithms do not require one.

A few other points:

- Graph vertices are traditionally numbered from 0 to `n` - 1. So unless your vertices have a payload (names, costs etc.), you can do away with the `vertices` array.
- Consider naming your class `UndirectedGraph` to make it clear that the graph is undirected (that is, whenever `v` appears in the list of `u`'s neighbors, `u` also appears in the list of `v`'s neighbors.
- Consider using a `List<Integer>` for your adjacency lists and implement it as a `LinkedList`. Most graph algorithms need only the ability to iterate over adjacency lists, not random access (which an `ArrayList` provides).
- `addEdge()` performs no validation. Depending on where the input is coming from, you might want to check that 0 ≤ `u, v` < `vertexCount` and that the edge `(u, v)` does not already exist.

I included the `main()` method in the same class for brevity.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class UndirectedGraph {
  private Vector<List<Integer>> edges;
  private int vertexCount = 0;

  public UndirectedGraph(int vertexCount) {
    this.vertexCount = vertexCount;
    edges = new Vector<List<Integer>>(vertexCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++){
      edges.addElement(new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }
  }

  public void addEdge(int u, int v) {
    edges.get(u).add(v);
    edges.get(v).add(u);
  }

  public int getNumberVertices() {
    return vertexCount;
  }

  public Object getAdjacentVertices(int u) {
    return edges.get(u);
  }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    UndirectedGraph g = new UndirectedGraph(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < g.getNumberVertices(); i++) {
      System.out.println("Neighbors of node " + i + ": " + g.getAdjacentVertices(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you C.Francu this is more clear now. Except that it is supposed to be a directed graph. Something like:   A: B->D; B: D->E...How would this be represented with an array where each index (vertex) is connected to a linked list that contains the edges that vertex is adjacent to....Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Ah, ok then. I was thrown off by the fact that your original code added each edge `(source, destination)` to both nodes' adjacency lists. If the graph is directed, then in `addEdge()` you only have to call the first addition. So you call `edges.get(u).add(v);`, but not `edges.get(v).add(u);`.